# What is the best way to share a file with multiple groups with Google Drive API removing multiple parents?

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm currently using the Google Drive API and multiple parents to share a file to multiple "groups" of people. So instead of updating permissions on the specific file, access can be added or removed on the folders the files are placed in, which makes sharing to many people a lot simpler.

With this functionality being removed and replaced with shortcuts (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-single-parent), what is the best way to programmatically share a file to a group of people? As I understand it, creating a shortcut in a folder does not mean that the file the shortcuts point to inherits the permission of the folder.

> The original file’s permissions don’t automatically update when you create a shortcut to it. Remember to give any new users access to the original file.

https://support.google.com/drive/answer/9700156

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using Groups:

- [Create a Group](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/groups/insert) for each different "group" of people you want to share files with.
- When sharing the file with [Permissions.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create), set the permission **type** to **group**, and provide the Group **emailAddress** in the request.

#### Reference:

- [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/d/homeredir)
- [Permissions.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create)